# How to Set file permissions- Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file

I have a doc file on sdcard.

I want to open it in read-only mode. Also I don't want the document viewer to save the file.

The intent to open the file is as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File("/sdcard/test.doc");
file.setReadOnly();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION );
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/msword");
startActivity(intent);
```

But when the file opens in quickOffice, the file is still editable.

Please suggest how should I make the file ready-only to any document viewer and how should I prevent file from saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because your app does not have root access. File permissions can be changed by root access only.

Comment: I am facing a strange problem. I am running the same code(Mentioned above) in android 2.3 and Android3.0 . In 2.3 there is no effect of setting read-only flag. But in 3.0 the file open with read-only mode. i.e. I was not able to edit the file in quickoffice installed in 3.0. How is this possible.

Comment: I have never tried it on 3.0, but I faced the same problem in 2.2 and 2.3 and the reason is probably what I mentioned above. In 3.0 they must have removed the root access requirement.